# Insights from RMSE Value

Tags: regression

My data lies in the range -0.0275 to 0.99 and I am using Linear Regression. The RMSE value that I get is 0.14. What does this mean? Is it a good fit? Can you help or provide any material for getting insight from the RMSE value of the model?

Comment: Historically, when early statisticians ran regressions they wanted to determine how well their regression model fit the data. One measure of fit quality would be the "average magnitude of error". This can be found by taking the absolute value of the errors and calculating the mean, or average, value. However "absolute value" is not a differentiable function in the calculus, so they instead squared all errors to make them positive, took the mean of those squared errors, and then took the square root of that mean. This is where the term Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE) comes from.

Comment: So what does 0.14 error mean on my data? Does this mean that error rate of my model is 14%?

Comment: RMSE is effectively the average error size, and is not a percentage. If the data being modeled has units of liters, then in effect the average size of the errors would be 0.14 liters.